# ¿Cómo concatenar 2 campos a mostrar en un combo de una referencia @ManyToOne con @DescriptionsList en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

La relación @ManyToOne en OpenXava sólo me permite buscar en una tabla con un combo box desde otra tabla por un campo descripcion (un campo únicamente). Por ejemplo, si escribo:

```
@DescriptionsList
@ManyToOne
Producto producto
```

Obtengo un combo con el campo descripción de todos los productos.

Mi plan es coger dos campos, como nombre y apellidos, y concatenarlos en una única cadena a mostrar en el combo.

¿Cómo puedo unir dos campos en un combo de un @DescriptionsList?

Answer (score 0):

El atributo descriptionProperties de @DescriptionsList te permite especificar varias propiedades separadas por comas, por lo que puedes escribir:

```
@ManyToOne
@DescriptionsList(descriptionProperties="apellidos, nombre")
private Cliente cliente;
```